# No matching configuration of project react-native-background-geolocation was found

Tags: react-native, background, geolocation

I'm trying to install `@mak12/react-native-background-geolocation` a fork of `@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation` but keeps getting the following error message:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :mak12_react-native-background-geolocation.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :mak12_react-native-background-geolocation was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component  
preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.1' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

Can anyone explain this error for me, and possibly how to fix it?